# "in" operator chaining ( True in [True] in [True] OUTPUT: False )

Tags: python, list, operators, operator-precedence

I'm trying to figure out in what order this code runs:

```
print( True in [True] in [True] )
False
```

even though:

```
print( ( True in [True] ) in [True] )
True
```

and:

```
print( True in ( [True] in [True] ) )
TypeError
```

If the first code is neither of these two last ones, then what?

Comment: hmm, I would assume right-to-left in this case

Comment: you need a comma in the last example to avoid a TypeError: `print( True in ( [True] in [True], ) )`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`in` is comparing with chaining there so

```
True in [True] in [True]
```

is equivalent to (except middle `[True]` is evaluated once)

```
(True in [True]) and ([True] in [True])
```

which is

```
True and False
```

which is

```
False
```

This is all similar to

```
2 < 4 < 12
```

operation which is equivalent to `(2 < 4) and (4 < 12)`.

Answer (score 1):

> `print( True in [True] in [True] )`

This is actually interpreted as - `True in [True] and [True] in [True]` which gives you false because it becomes - `True and False`

> `print( ( True in [True] ) in [True] )`

The `( True in [True] )` is checked first, so you get `True in [True]` which is True.

> `print( True in ( [True] in [True] ) )`

The second part is checked, before the first because of parenthesis which changes the order, so it becomes - `True in True`. And `True` which is a boolean, is not a iterable, so you cannot use `in`, and then you get TypeError